# ImportError: No module named authentication

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I have installed the MySQL Connector/Python module. It shows up in the directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/. I have also added this directory to the $PATH.

When I execute the following Python program, I get the below error.

```
import mysql.connector
config = {
    "database": "XXXX",
    "host": "XXXX",
    'user': 'XXXX',
    "password": "XXXX",
    "table": "XXXX",
    "charset": "utf8"
}

try:
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)

except mysql.connector.Error as err:
  if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
    print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
  elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
    print("Database does not exists")
  else:
    print(err)
else:
  cnx.close()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "config.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/protocol.py", line 34, in <module>
ImportError: No module named authentication
```

In the directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/, there is an authentication.py and authentication.pyc.

I don't understand the issue...

Comment: In the file "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/protocol.py" try changing `from .authentication import get_auth_plugin` to `from mysql.connector.authentication import get_auth_plugin`.

Comment: I have made the suggest change.. but get exactly the same error. What is the authentication plug-in? I see get_auth_plugin() is defined in authentication.py

Comment: Are you sure you added the dir to the PYTHONPATH? This is the kind of behaviour if you didn't: http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/understanding-imports-and-pythonpath

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have checked `PYTHONPATH` and it includes a link to `'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages'`. So I assume `import mysql.connector` allows me to use `mysql.connector.connect()` in my Python code as `mysql/connector` is a subdirectory of the `../site-packages` directory

Comment: I found the issue. The `mysql` directory and subdirectories where only readable from a `root` account and not from normal user accounts. @xbello - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that the directory and the files making up the MySQL package was in PYTHONPATH, but had no read rights (apart from root). The answer is to `chmod a+x` the directory and `chmod a+r *.py` the files in that directory and subdirectory.